# Visual Studio and TFS 2008 inability to check in, shelf, or query work items

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Don't know if anyone has encountered anything like this before, but I'm working with two machines - one has VS2012, one VS2015.  I'm not having any issues on VS2015, but am on VS2012 when it comes to TFS 2008 connectivity.

Note that it is only recently this has started, previously I was able to check-in, shelf, etc.  Not sure what changed.

Team explorer home:

[image]

In the above, new query is grayed out, it did not used to be.

If I click work items:

[image]

I found a few articles that seem to be around a similar issue, but they did not solve my problem.

Things I've tried:

1. [Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component VS2012 when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361199/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-vs2012-whe) - did not seem to apply to me as I don't even have a project open, I'm just trying to access TFS.
2. [Buid definition: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447672/buid-definition-error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-com)

Not sure if there's a place I can look for a more detailed error message or not, but the error is preventing me from getting a whole lot done on this machine.  I am still able to view and navigate through source control explorer, builds, get the reports I have access too, etc.

Comment: Did you try clearing your local user cache? 

devenv /resetuserdata

Comment: What patch level is VS2012 at? If it's not on Update 5, make sure it is.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the items below:

1. Install Update5 for your VS2012. Check Client compatibility at [this website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/requirements).
2. Clean the cache folder on your client machine: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache.
3. Try resetting settings and add-in settings (`devenv /ResetSettings`) and (`devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`), try rebuilding all templates (`devenv /setup`) for your VS2012.
4. Check Event log in Event Viewer to see if there is anything helpful.

Comment: I tried all of these except VS2012 update5, I'll convey that to our group that can actually install updates to our machines.  None of the others worked - though I did update the question body to state that is has worked in the past, it has only recently stopped functioning for some reason.

Comment: Please check this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smondal/2013/03/08/error-hresult-e_fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component/, and try the solution Start —> Run —> regsvr32  %SystemRoot%\System32\msxml3.dll, Start —> Run —> regsvr32  %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\msxml3.dll.